# Deleting/Removing a 'Window'?

Tags: animation

I'm sorry, but I am not familiar with the name of the tools. So, I'm just going to put in an image instead showing my problem. Than I will add to it.[image] Now, the red X's is what I was calling 'Windows'. How do I remove the ones I no longer need? Because so far, the only way I have found is saving.. closing out.. than reopening again. And I know there has to be a better way.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the line that divides the two windows (See picture below)
2. Click "join area"
3. Mouse over the area you want to be deleted and click

[image]